# Swiftmailer - HTML corrompido no recebimento

Tags: php, email, yii, smtp, swiftmailer

Estou tendo problemas com o Swiftmailer quando eu envio uma mensagem e, por vezes, eu recebo reclamações de que o conteúdo está completamente quebrado (HTML removido).

Meu software envia um monte de e-mails, e esse problema acontece quase todos os dias, mas não conseguimos obter qualquer log que tenha o motivo. Já que estamos usando Yii como nosso framework principal e utilizamos a ferramenta de rastreamento de log (e trace) que apresenta o email corretamente não temos como obter sucesso na razão do problema.

Para melhorar nós mudamos parte do código do Swiftmailer para realizar a quebra de linha antes do strip_tags utilizado por padrão no método msgHTML(), o problema é que os usuários não estão vendo a parte text/plain do email, mas o HTML tratado pelo cliente (sem nenhuma tag e todo junto).

Apenas uma observação, estamos usando relay para enviar através do SMTP do Outlook Exchange (porta 25 e sem autenticação). Conversamos com o pessoal do suporte da Microsoft e eles relataram que esse problema deve estar em nossa ferramenta.

Comment: Chegou a printar a saída antes de enviar o email para analisar se realmente esta quebrado ??

Comment: Sim, o conteúdo está perfeito. O html está bem estruturado, o que eu achava que poderia ser um dos motivos para acontecer o problema.

Comment: acho que seria legal colocar o html tambem para ajudar na analise, nunca tive problema com o swiftmailer de corromper o html porém é bom ver como ele esta e se esta 100%

Comment: @Otto Segue o HTML que obtivemos no log de um email que teve relato do problema, link do pastebin: [HTML](http://pastebin.com/WxHUyZmn)

Comment: o pastebin esta bloqueado aqui na empresa vejo depois isto para tentar te ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Sem ver o seu código fica meio difícil, mas tive um problema parecido.

Estava utilizando assim:

```
$html = $this->renderPartial('view',array(),true);
```

Foi resolvido trocando o `renderPartial()` para um `render()` com alguns ajustes:

```
$this->layout = 'layout-email';
$html = $this->render('view',array(),true);
$this->layout = 'layout-da-pagina';
```